# Changing background color in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to change the background (black color) to a different color in kivy. But the Color specification in kv file is not recognized.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MatrixCalcLayout(BoxLayout):
    def calculations(self):
        pass

class ConfusionMatrixCalcApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ConfusionMatrixCalcApp().run()
```

ConfusionMatrixCalc.kv file

```
MatrixCalcLayout:

<MatrixCalcLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After **Color** you need to draw something, in your case, a **Rectangle**

```
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
    Rectangle: #woohoo!!!
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
```